# How to dispose of the Presenter when using MVP in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

A cut down Example of a UserControl using MVP:

INTERFACE:

```
namespace AuditTest.View
{
    public interface IEditFindingView
    {
        string ITxtFindingNumber_Text { get; set; }

        Image ILblFindingDate_Image { get; set; }

        DateTime IDtpFindingDate_Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

USERCONTROL CLASS:

```
namespace AuditTest.View
{
    public partial class EditFindingView : UserControl, IEditFindingView
    {

        public string ITxtFindingNumber_Text
        {
            get { return TxtFindingNumber.Text; }
            set { TxtFindingNumber.Text = value; }
        }

        public Image ILblFindingDate_Image
        {
            get { return LblFindingDate.Image; }
            set { LblFindingDate.Image = value; }
        }

        public DateTime IDtpFindingDate_Value
        {
            get { return DtpFindingDate.Value; }
            set { DtpFindingDate.Value = value; }
        }

        public EditFindingView(int index)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            new EditFindingPres(this, index);
        }
    }
}
```

PRESENTER CLASS:

```
namespace AuditTest.View
{
    public class EditFindingPres
    {
        private IEditFindingView View = null;
        private AuditFindingMod Model = null;
        private int FindingIndex = 0;

        public EditFindingPres(IEditFindingView view, int index) : this(view, index, new AuditFindingMod())
        {
        }

        public EditFindingPres(IEditFindingView view, int index, AuditFindingMod model)
        {
            try
            {
                if (view != null)
                {
                    View = view;
                    Model = model;
                    FindingIndex = index;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("IEditFindingView");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                new ErrorMod().LogError(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), ex, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This UserControl is created and Disposed of often while using the system. I have noticed that the Presenter is not being Disposed of though. What do I need to do to Dispose of the Presenter when the UserControl has been Disposed of?

Comment: If you know the ` View` is disposed, why do you need to dispose the presenter? Does it contain something which needs to be disposed? If yes, then it's presenter responsibility to control the disposal of the view and other disposable things.

Comment: Your presenter class doesn't appear to implement `IDisposable`, so I don't think you need to worry about it.

Comment: I was under the impression from some other posts in other forums that the Presenter should be disposed of. I am not sure if this is the case though.